# Change DataGridView Cell Value Programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview which has a datatable as data source. I need to change some cell values manually. For example, if cell input value contains character 'g', it must change "abc" automatically when I leave cell. Following code checks the formatted value of current cell:

```
private void dgwPNotlar_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex<2||e.ColumnIndex>4||e.FormattedValue.ToString()=="")
  {
    return;
  }

  if (e.FormattedValue.ToString().Contains('G')||e.FormattedValue.ToString().Contains('g'))
  {
    dgwPNotlar.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
    dgwPNotlar.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "abc";
    dgwPNotlar.EndEdit();
    dgwPNotlar.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
    return;
  }
}
```

When the code "dgwPNotlar.EndEdit();" runs, the cell value I changed is "abc", returns to previous value as "g" or "G"..

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes.
@LarsTech answer is the best and simplest solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The changing of the cell needs to happen *after* the validating event, so try the CellValidated event instead:

```
void dgv_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  string cellValue = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();
  if (cellValue.Contains('G') || cellValue.Contains('g')) {
    dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = "abc";
  }
}
```

Comment: answer is the best and simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here´s my code in VB applying his solution:

```vb
Private Sub dataGridView_CellValidated(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dataGridView.CellValidated

    Dim cellValue As String = dataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString()
    If (cellValue.Contains(".")) Then
        cellValue = cellValue.Replace(".", ",")
        dataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = cellValue
    End If
End Sub
```